# AR Cloud Anchor Hosting Error: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED Android

Tags: android, firebase

I am getting this error on Android after setting up the cloud anchor quick start sample app https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/cloud-anchors/cloud-anchors-quickstart-android.

Here is the logcat when error occurs:

```
05-10 17:52:07.258 3214-3273/com.google.ar.core.examples.java.cloudanchor E/zygote64: The String#value field is not present on Android versions >= 6.0
05-10 17:52:07.528 3214-3273/com.google.ar.core.examples.java.cloudanchor E/AnchorServiceClient: AnchorServiceClient Exception
    aua: PERMISSION_DENIED: The request is missing a valid API key.
        at bhd.a(PG:58)
        at bhd.a(PG:29)
        at com.google.ar.persistence.AnchorServiceClient.a(PG:17)
        at com.google.ar.persistence.AnchorServiceClient.createAnchors(PG:26)
```

I have:

1. Added app to Firebase project that contains realtime DB. Set up Rule for public.
2. Enabled Cloud Anchor
   API, and added API key in Cloud credentials and then in manifest.

Here is a copy of the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.google.ar.core.examples.java.cloudanchor">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <!-- This tag indicates that this application requires ARCore.  This results in the application
       only being visible in the Google Play Store on devices that support ARCore. -->
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar" android:required="true"/>

  <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.ar.API_KEY"
      android:value="**obsured**"/>

  <application
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="false"
      tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

    <activity
        android:name=".CloudAnchorActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="locked">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- This tag indicates that this application requires ARCore.  This results in the Google Play
         Store downloading and installing ARCore along with the application.
         Application code must still call ArCoreApk.requestInstall() before beginning an ARCore
         sessions, in case the user uninstalls ARCore for any reason. -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="required" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Before even attempting to do the Android version, I set up the iOS quick start sample app and that works fine - I can be a host, add an object and then resolve and find the object.

The Android version is to communicate with the same Firebase DB that iOS app did and is to demonstrate cloud anchors across iOS and Android.

I have also tried setting up the Android sample app with a new Firebase project and get the same error on Android.

If there is anyone who has tried AR Cloud Anchor for Android, please let me know why the API key is being rejected by the Google Cloud Platform while the iOS version works just fine with the same backend set up.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my own question.

Looks like the:

```
      <meta-data
         android:name="com.google.android.ar.API_KEY"
         android:value="**obsured**"/>
...
```

needs to be placed within the Application element in the manifest file like this:

```
<application
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="false"
      tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.ar.API_KEY"
        android:value="**obsured**"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".CloudAnchorActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="locked">
...
```